# Pandas exclude rows based on dynamic condition set from configuration file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

As title suggest, I have a rule engine in xml format which contains column name and values to exlcule.

```
 <ExclusionSet>
    <Exclude Excl="Col1:A" Count="1"/>
    <Exclude Excl="Col2:BB,BBB" Count="1"/>
    <Exclude Excl="Col3:A1B" Count="1"/>
    <Exclude Excl="Col1:A2" Excl="Col2:BC" Count="2"/>
 </ExclusionSet>
```

based on the above condition I need to exclude rows. i.e. row where Col1 has value A, Col2 has value BB and value BBB, Col3 has value A1B.

I was able to get a working code for the single condition (first 3) but unable to figure out how to implement last condition (with more than one condition)

```
def exclusionEngine(config,df):

    #parsing xml
    xml_map = minidom.parse(config)
    value_map = xml_map.getElementsByTagName('Exclude')
    exclusion_df = pd.DataFrame()

    #iterating conditions
    for atrb in value_map:
        #not using Count any where but thought it might be useful for multiple conditions.
        rule_count = atrb.attributes['Count'].value
        for count in range(1,int(rule_count)+1):        
            #column name
            col = atrb.attributes['Excl'].value.split(':')[0]
            # value(s) as a list
            value = list(atrb.attributes['Excl'].value.split(':')[1].split(','))
            
            #creating filter for exclusion ; if there is way to implement multiple filters dynamically or create a list of filters and apply it.
            filter1 = df[col].isin(value)
        
        df = df.loc[~(filter1)]
           
    return df
```

expecting something as follows but dynamic as there could be more conditions or less.

```
df = df.loc[~(filter1 & filter2)]
```

EDIT:
To simplify the ask here, is it possible to evaluate multiple conditions dynamically ?

```
<Exclude Excl="Col1:A2" Excl="Col2:BC" Count="2"/>
```

Comment: minidom raised an error for me, seems that it cannot read duplicate xml attributes, so I posted an answer without actually using it

Answer (score 1):

You could use the pandas `query` method. I am dropping all the non related xml stuff, as it is not going to work (you have a duplicate attribute so the supplied text is not a valid xml)

```
import pandas as pd
import re
def exclusionEngine(config: str,df: pd.DataFrame):
    ret_df = df.copy()
    with open(config, 'r') as inp:
        for line in inp.readlines():
            if '</ExclusionSet>' in line:
                read = False
                continue
            if 'ExclusionSet' in line:
                read = True
                continue
            if read:
                matches = re.findall("Excl\=\"(.*?)\"", line)
                query = 'not (' + ' & '.join([f'({col}=="{x}")' for match in matches for col,x in [match.rstrip().split(':')]]) + ')'
                ret_df = ret_df.query(query)
    return ret_df
```

So for example if we have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'B1', 'C1'], ['O', 'C', 'D'], ['B', 'A', 'C'], ['M', 'BB,BBB', 'A'], ['A2', 'H', 'B'], ['A2', 'BC', 'y']], columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])
```

```
  Col1  Col2    Col3
0   A   B1  C1
1   O   C   D
2   B   A   C
3   M   BB,BBB  A
4   A2  H   B
5   A2  BC  y
```

and config is saved inside 'config.xml' then calling `exclusionEngine('config.xml', df)` returns:

```
    Col1    Col2    Col3
1   O   C   D
2   B   A   C
4   A2  H   B
```

Comment: Please do not forget to accept it as best answer if it has answered your question, or add a comment if not, feedback always is worthwhile

Answer (score 0):

I think what you looking for is this:

```
df = df.loc[~(filter1 ^ filter2)]
```

This also will give you the same result:

```
df.loc[~filter1 & ~filter2]
```